# Where are Wireless Profiles stored in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, networkmanager

Where does Ubuntu store profiles that allow it to remember the credentials to private wireless networks that it has previously authenticate to and used?

I just replaced my Uncle's hard drive with a new one and installed Ubuntu 10.04 on it (he had Ubuntu 9.10 on his old hard drive.

He is at my house right now, and I want him to be able to access his private wireless network when he gets home. Usually, when I upgrade Ubuntu, I have his /home directory on another partition, so his wireless profile to his own network persists.

However, right now, I'm trying to figure out which .folder I need to copy from his /home/user folder on the old hard drive, to the new hard drive, so that he will be able to have wireless Internet when he gets home.

Does anyone know with certainty, exactly which folder I need to copy to the new hard drive to achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> **/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections**

You will find all of your connections in this directory.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, just copying the files was not enough. The MAC address in the files also had to be changed. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/870661/8822) for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Check the folder `.gconf/system/networking/` in your old home directory . Then check VPN or wireless, whichever you want and the *profiles* should be there.

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on a few things. One location will be `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` and another could be `/etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora 23, the wireless profiles are stored in:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$SSID
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/keys-$SSID
```